# Any idea how i can i make a browser extension with nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, web, google-chrome-extension, nuxt.js, browser-extension

First time I ask for something here, so I hope I'm clear enough! ( don't judge me ... )

I need to build a web extension but for many reasons related to the way of working in my company I need to do it with nuxt, was looking on stack overflow, medium and basically all the internet and it's like no one has ever done this, is there a reason? Can anyone help me do it?

Btw my first idea was to extend the build config in nuxt.config.js but I don't know much about webpack either so I guess it will be difficult and I don't even know if it's possible or if it's the right way to do it.

Any help is welcome! Have a nice day.

Comment: I would love to see a POC of this.